# PHP Array Size Loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, input

We need to create a program that lets the user input the array size, their name, and age (depending on the array size the user entered). After that, we need to display all the elements of the array.

This is my code, but I'm having a problem adding a new element for another user and displaying it.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> PHP Array </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="example.php">
            <h3> Please enter the your information: </h3>
                Array Size: <input type="text" name="arraysize"/> <br/><br>
                Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br/><br/>
                Age: <input type="text" name="age"/> <br/><br/>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
            <input type="reset" name="cancel" value="Cancel"/><br/><br/>

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                
                if((!empty($_POST['name'])) && (!empty($_POST['age'])) && (!empty($_POST['arraysize']))){
                
                $info = array($_POST['arraysize'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['g6ave']);
                $arraylength = count($info);

                    for ($i=0; $i<=$arraylength ; $i++) { 
                        
                        $name = $_POST['name'];
                            for ($j=1; $j<=$i; $j++){
                                echo "User's Name" .$i. ": " .$name. [$j] ."<br>";

                        $age = $_POST['age'];
                            for($k=0; $k<=$i; $k++){
                                echo "User's Age: " .$age. [$k] ."<br/>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow iastje_ll. *"but I'm having a problem adding a new element for another user and displaying it"* - may i know where the submitted data stored in? `$_POST` only has the value for the current request, it wont give you old data.

Comment: @BagusTesa I only stored it in $_POST. I didn't know that it will not give the old data

Comment: there are many ways to tackle this problem, some that i could think off: 1) use javascript to create more form entry pair that contains `name` and `age` then have them submitted at the same time; 2) use php `session` to store past submission data; 3) create more input form with values taken from the previous submission

Comment: Is this a 2 steps form issue like I entered array size as 4 & the second page asks me 4 fields to populate by me or only a 1 step form issue (just entering array size is 4 and the system automatically populates the array & display it)?this is important to your solution.

Comment: @Ersin yes that is the issue by what you formerly said

Comment: i'll try to answer asap for the case that *"2 steps form issue like I entered array size as 4 & the second page asks me 4 fields to populate by me"*

Answer (score 0):

One approach (of other possible approaches) below should give you the main ideas. I also commented the aim of the each script part.

*Approach below assumes that you'll use same URL for all your form pages. (1st, 2nd and the success page)*

I hope this helps.

```
session_start(); //Start new or resume existing session

if (isset($_SESSION['form_success']) && $_SESSION['form_success'] === true)
{
    require 'success_page.php';
    unset($_SESSION['form_success']); // don't needed anymore
    return; //not to continue to execute the code
}

// decide the page from user
if (isset($_POST['page']))
{
    $page = $_POST['page'];
}
else
{
    // display the first form page for the 1st time
    require 'first_page_form.php';
    return; //not to continue to execute the code
}

// if the first page was submitted.
if ($page === 'first') // or a specific POST flag from 1st page
{
    //verify data from first page
    $warnings = [];
    if (first_page_data_valid() === true) 
    {
        require 'second_page_form.php';
        return; //not to continue to execute the code       
    }
    // populate $warnings during first_page_data_valid()
    //if first page data are invalid
    print_r($warnings);
    require 'first_page_form.php'; //display again
    return; //not to continue to execute the code   
}

// if the second page was submitted.
if ($page === 'second') // or a specific POST flag from 2nd page
{
    //verify data from second page
    $warnings = [];
    if (second_page_data_valid() === true) // populate $warnings during second_page_data_valid()
    {
        // do things. ex: DB operations.
        if (db_actions_success() === true)
        {
            $_SESSION['form_success'] = true; // defined and set to true.
            // PHP permanent URL redirection. usage of 301 is important.
            // it clears POST content. Prevents F5/refresh.
            header("Location: https://www.url.com/form.php", true, 301);
            exit; // good/recommended to use after redirect     
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'System down or I have a bug. Try again later.';
            return; //not to continue to execute the code   
        }
    }
    
    //if second page data is invalid
    print_r($warnings);
    require 'second_page_form.php'; //display again
    return; //not to continue to execute the code   
}
```